# Connecting Qt slots and signals from a C++98 interface with no Qt, STL or Boost

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing an audio rendering library that takes as input audio buffers, does some magic, then manage playback on a selected device. For this task, I decided to use Qt's QAudioOutput class.

I would like to allow the user to set callbacks when the state of the QAudioOutput object state changes (active, suspended, stopped and idle). I would connect these signals to a signal handler that would call the user-defined callbacks. However, I have the following restriction: no STL, no Qt, no Boost on the library header. I also need to stay compatible with C++98.

Right now, I have 2 solutions (with drawbacks) and I am looking to improve the design. My first solution was:

```
// library header
class AudioLibrary
{
    typedef void ( *Callback )();
    void setOnActiveCallback( Callback cb );
};
```

The problem with this solution is that the client can only pass static functions or non-capturing lambdas. This is too restrictive. Imagine a client who wants to do something as simple as re-enabling a button once playback finished. Not possible if the button is a member variable.

My second solution was that my interface would be an abstract class and contains pure virtual functions that would contain the desired behavior on state change. However, I am not sure this would be much fun for the client of the library...

Is there a cleaner and/or better solution that I ommited to think of?

Comment: You can use QAudioOutputs signals, notify() and stateChanged().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-style callbacks without a means to pass context **are completely utterly broken and your users will hate you for that**. Don't do it. As soon as you have a `intptr_t` or `void*` typed context object, you can pass anything you wish to the callback, and quite efficiently at that. Yes, you can pass capturing lambdas, member methods, etc.

E.g.:

```
class AudioLibrary {
  typedef void (*Callback)(void*);
  void setOnActiveCallback(Callback cb, void * context);
};
```

Then:

```
static void functionCallback(void * context) {
  auto f = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(context);
  f();
}

struct User {
  AudoLibrary * m_audio;
  std::function<void()> f_onActive{std::bind(&User::onActive, this)};
  void onActive();
  User(AudioLibrary * audio) : m_audio(audio) {
    audio->setOnActiveCallback(functionCallback, &f_member);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a C style callback.

```
class AudioLibrary
{
    typedef void ( *Callback )( void * );
    void setOnActiveCallback( Callback cb, void * context );

    // Perhaps also include
    template <typename Func>
    void setOnActiveCallback( Func & f )
    {
        setOnActiveCallback( &Func::operator(), &f );
    }
};
```